# Removing rows of a matrix with at least one NA in R

Tags: r, matrix, rows, na

I am trying to remove the rows of a matrix in R. My criteria for row removal is that the column contains *at least one* `NA` (note that the entire row does not need to be `NA` like in other questions on this site).

For example, if matrix A looks like the following

```
32  54  34
NA  10  NA
17  93  NA
```

Only the first row should remain.

This is what I am trying, but I am getting a column instead of a row.

```
newMatrix <- A[,rowSums(apply(A, 1, is.na))<1]
#A is a matrix
```

What am I missing? I tried doing `!is.na`, but R didn't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `na.omit` function:

```
x <- matrix(c(32, 54, 34, NA, 10, NA, 17, 93, NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
na.omit(x)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   32   54   34
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 2 3
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: `matrix[complete.cases(matrix),]`